# Subscribe not working Spring SockJs Stomp

Tags: spring, websocket, stomp, sockjs, subscribe

I want to use websocket to send from server to client something.. 
Here's my code:

---- Websocket configuration on server ----

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
@Slf4j
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer{

@Override
public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
    config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
}

@Override
public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
    registry.addEndpoint("/myWebSocketEndPoint")
            .withSockJS();
    }
}
```

---- Controller---

```
@Controller
@Component
@Slf4j
public class MenuItemController{
    @SendTo("/topic/notification")
    public String sendToMenuItems(MenuItemDto menuItem)  {
        return menuItem.getMenuItemName();
    }
}
```

----- Client ----

```
var SockJS = require('sockjs-client');
var Stomp = require('stompjs'); 

let connectWebSocket = () => {
  socket = new SockJS(context.backend + '/myWebSocketEndPoint');
  stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
  stompClient.connect({},function (frame) {
    console.log(frame);
    stompClient.subscribe('/topic/notification', function(menuItem){
        alert(menuItem);
    });
  });
}
connectWebSocket();
```

I use context.backend because i use webpack, so websocket connect over the backend server. It works for connect and also subscribe seems working, but when i send something from server to client, the alert doesn't appear and in console there are no message incoming by websocket. What's my problem? I hope someone can help me.. =D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a issue related: https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-messaging-stomp-websocket/issues/10

use

```
stompClient.connect({}, function(frame) {
```

instead of

```
stompClient.connect("","",function (frame) {
```

Edit:
If you are wondering to use Rest Controller please use SimpMessagingTemplate to send your messages.

```
@Autowired
private SimpMessagingTemplate messagingTemplate;
```

and your method will call

```
messagingTemplate.convertAndSend("/topic/notification", "test");
```

If not, be sure to annotate your sendToMenuItems with `@MessageMapping(value = "/sentToMenu")` and you have a proper stomp client sending a message: `stompClient.send("/sentToMenu", {}, 'teste');`

Comment: Please see your browser console (f12) and paste the whole log. Also consider to put .setAllowedOrigins("*") on your registry object for a possible cors problem.

Comment: I try your suggestion and i see and run your code! When I run your code, everything works well! But when i run my code with:

        messagingTemplate.convertAndSend("/topic/notification","test");

it throws a NullPointerException because messagingTemplate is null! =( I declare it with @Autowired, i dont' know why it say me this..

Comment: Are you using a custom @ComponentScan? If yes, be sure that the package of the controller is cover. @ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.x.y.*") at your main spring boot class. And also see your folder structure.